# Vue Bootsrap toast hides after split second

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I want to add a toast message after clicking on save button and sending data to API.
I have added below, to my code, toast message appears on the screen but hides in a blink of an eye.

Should I add something more? Or there is another way to use messages after actions, maybe use alerts instead of toasts?

Thanks for all your answers!

```
axiosInstance
    .put(`{{here is my endpoint}}`, payload)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      let notificationToast = (vm, append = false) => {
        vm.$bvToast.toast(`This is toast`, {
          title: "BootstrapVue Toast",
          autoHideDelay: 5000,
          appendToast: append,
          noAutoHide: true
        });
      };
      notificationToast(this, true);
    });
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: I reproduce your issue in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/impala69/csdq23nx/15/. Are you using `bootstrap-vue` with `CDN` links or ` using a module bundler`?

Comment: @ImanShafiei The reason it's not working in your fiddle is because you're including Bootstrap 5, and not Bootstrap 4. Perhaps OP has the same issue. Here the fiddle using Bootstrap 4. https://jsfiddle.net/6n2qh5tx/

Comment: Yeah, this might be actually the case, I have Bootstrap 5... Need to switch back to 4 and test

Comment: Interesting coincidence, thanks @Hiws, I think the problem now can be solved.